# Google Chrome Not Showing Image in Print Preview

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, popup

I have some code to create a pop-up write some html and print. Google Chrome is not showing images in the print preview, but other browsers are working fine. The file `Logo_big.png` is missing in my case. How can I get it to work in Chrome also?

My code:

```
var newWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=100, height=100'),
        document = newWindow.document.open(),
        pageContent =
            '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
            '<html>' +
            '<head>' +
            '<meta charset="utf-8" />' +
            '<title>Inventory</title>' +
            '<style type="text/css">body {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; font-family: Arial; }</style>' +
            '</head>' +
            '<body><div><div style="width:33.33%; float:left;"><img src="img/Logo_big.png"/></body></html>';
        document.write(pageContent);
        document.close();
        newWindow.moveTo(0, 0);
        newWindow.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
        newWindow.print();
        newWindow.close();
```

Answer (score 42):

The issue here is javascript not giving the DOM enough (any) time to load / render the image once it has the `src` set.

You need to allow time for the browser to load / render (from cache or otherwise) the image, you can do so by setting a `setTimeout` to delay the printing from the content being set.

An example for this specific question would be:

```
var newWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=100, height=100'),
document = newWindow.document.open(),
pageContent =
    '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
    '<html>' +
    '<head>' +
    '<meta charset="utf-8" />' +
    '<title>Inventory</title>' +
    '<style type="text/css">body {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; font-family: Arial; }</style>' +
    '</head>' +
    '<body><div><div style="width:33.33%; float:left;"><img src="img/Logo_big.png"/></body></html>';
document.write(pageContent);
document.close();
newWindow.moveTo(0, 0);
newWindow.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
setTimeout(function() {
    newWindow.print();
    newWindow.close();
}, 250);
```

The lower you set the `setTimeout`, the less time the browser will have to load the image so you will need to adjust this and account for slower internet connections / browsers where applicable.

Comment: @gustavz Feel free to ping over some info on what your having an issue with https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213771/room-for-william-isted-and-gustavz

Comment: It works for me, You saved our time by a simple and short solution...

Comment: This certainly seems to be the correct answer. In my case, this solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

After a deep research I found a solution for showing the images and background in google chrome print preview:

```
function PopUp(data) {
    var mywindow = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=950,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,addressbar=0');

    var is_chrome = Boolean(mywindow.chrome);
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10 and necessary before onload for chrome

    if (is_chrome) {
        mywindow.onload = function() { // wait until all resources loaded 
            mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            mywindow.print();  // change window to mywindow
            mywindow.close();// change window to mywindow
        };
    }
    else {
        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thanks to Anand Deep Singh post that helped with a part of the code.

Answer (score 12):

You can add the following in your css for media print:

```
img {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to put delay before print. There is a native bug in chrome. Code would as under :-

```
function PrintDiv(data) {
    var mywindow = window.open();
    var is_chrome = Boolean(mywindow.chrome);
    mywindow.document.write(data);

    if (is_chrome) {
        setTimeout(function () { // wait until all resources loaded 
                mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
                mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
                mywindow.print();  // change window to winPrint
                mywindow.close();// change window to winPrint
        }, 250);
    }
    else {
        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a bug.As the print window is also a HTML page,it will have its own lifecycle.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jQuery you can use the "on load" event. This will wait until the entire page is ready (including Images). This should be useful if you have many images. **Note You will need to include the jQuery source in your html.**

Include the following in your html.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Your javaScript will now be.

```
var newWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=100, height=100'),
        document = newWindow.document.open(),
        pageContent =
            '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
            '<html>' +
            '<head>' +
            '<meta charset="utf-8" />' +
            '<title>Inventory</title>' +
            '<style type="text/css">body {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; font-family: Arial; }</style>' +
            '</head>' +
            '<body><div><div style="width:33.33%; float:left;"><img src="img/Logo_big.png"/></body></html>';
        document.write(pageContent);
        document.close();
        newWindow.moveTo(0, 0);
        newWindow.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
    $(newWindow.window).on("load", function () {
        newWindow.print();
        newWindow.close();
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two opening 'div' tags that are never closed.

Comment: I have deleted some content to make the snippet readable. but the issue persist

Comment: I have checked the html validity and passes

Answer (score 1):

```
var newWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=100, height=100'),
        pageContent =
        '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
        '<html>' +
        '<head>' +
        '<meta charset="utf-8" />' +
        '<title>Inventory</title>' +
        '<style type="text/css">body {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; font-family: Arial; } img{display:visible}</style>' +
        '</head>' +
        '<body><img src="img/Logo_big.png"/></body></html>';
    newWindow.document.write(pageContent);
    document.close();
newWindow.moveTo(0, 0);
newWindow.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
newWindow.print();
newWindow.close();
```

I hope that code works fine
Note that if image is not displayed so you need to specify absolute image url
Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution given by [Jesus Flores](https://stackoverflow.com/users/762218/jesus-flores) 
**BUT** it doesn't work when you cancel the print and then do it again.
So i used the *setTimeout()* function to tackle that situation,

```
function PopUp(data) {
    var mywindow = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=950,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,addressbar=0');

    var is_chrome = Boolean(mywindow.chrome);
    var isPrinting = false;
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10 and necessary before onload for chrome


    if (is_chrome) {
        mywindow.onload = function() { // wait until all resources loaded 
            isPrinting = true;
            mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            mywindow.print();  // change window to mywindow
            mywindow.close();// change window to mywindow
            isPrinting = false;
        };
        setTimeout(function () { if(!isPrinting){mywindow.print();mywindow.close();} }, 300);
    }
    else {
        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
    }

    return true;
}
```

This might be not the best way to do that so all kind of suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You have probably found the answer to this already, but I had a similar problem where my image wouldn't appear on print() method, but would appear when doing ctrl+p.  The solution to my issue was that I had only specified a width parameter on my img tag.  For whatever reason Chrome's print() method doesn't like this, so I added a height parameter to the img tag as well and it ended up printing the image.

I noticed within your code that you have neither parameter specified within your img tag.  My guess is by adding these parameters it should print your image.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution, you can show images in base64, it will fix this problem