# How to load image dynamically in printview using document.write function

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I'm trying to load the image dynamically by using `document.write` function. Please find the code below. The Image sometime gets loaded and sometimes it is not showing.

```
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>'+"Contract Approval Form"+'</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<div id="headerLogo"></div>');
    mywindow.document.write('<div id="watermarkDiv"></div>');
    mywindow.document.write('<div style="margin-top:50px;" id="content">' +printContent+ '</div>');
    var img = mywindow.document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'mylogo.png');
    mywindow.document.getElementById("headerLogo").appendChild(img);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');


    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

it's about waiting for the content to load

```
<script>
var printContent = '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
var mywindow = window.open('about:blank', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

//~ mywindow.onload = function() {
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>'+"Contract Approval Form"+'</title>');
mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
mywindow.document.write('<div id="headerLogo"></div>');
mywindow.document.write('<div id="watermarkDiv"></div>');
mywindow.document.write('<div style="margin-top:50px;" id="content">' +printContent+ '</div>');
var img = mywindow.document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', 'mylogo.png');
img.onload = function() {
    // now you can print, need to wait for image to load - which connotes you need to work out how to wait for all content to load
    mywindow.focus();
    mywindow.print();

}

mywindow.document.getElementById("headerLogo").appendChild(img);
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Found solution from** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725373/google-chrome-not-showing-image-in-print-preview):

Seems I need to use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
newWindow.print();
newWindow.close();
}, 250);
```

Comment: setTimeout works too, but onload is the better solution.